# Remove a Panel object from a form without deleting all of its child objects

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have about a dozen objects on a form design. They are all carefully placed by manually changing their locations and everything to get around the snap to grid.

Once I got everything done, I wanted just a square shape around the whole thing, so I used the Panel object (which appeared to be the most like a square frame of all the objects available). Well apparently this Panel object has attached itself to all the objects inside it.

If I resize the panel, it moves all the objects with it. If I delete the panel, it deletes all my objects from my form.

---

**QUESTION** Is there a way to just delete the panel without having to cut and paste each child object? It was a mistake to add the panel and now it owns my whole form :(. I googled this but all the questions and answers seem to relate to using panels in code. I just want it gone from the form designer.

Comment: Paragraphs are a wonderful thing.  Drag the mouse to capture all the controls, deselect the panel if it gets selected, CtrlC, delete the Panel Then Ctrl V.  Or just drag each off the panel

Comment: If I drag the mouse around the whole thing, it selects only the Panel. It thinks this is a single object not a bunch of separate objects.

Comment: Drag it *inside* the panel around the controls only

Comment: That solved it. Thanks.

Comment: What object can I use to make a frame without having it bind everything to itself?

Comment: What would be the point?  You either want a Container Control or you dont.  You could draw some lines but again whats the point if they are not really grouped?

Comment: You can also use Document Outline (View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline) to move controls between the containers. Unfortunately it doesn't support multi selection, so you have to do that one by one.

Comment: The point is to make the form more attractive for the user by dividing controls that belong together into a section. But I don't want that to force me to group all my controls into a single object, since I am still in the process of making changes to the form. Anyway, I solved it by using a Rectangle object in the "Visual Basic PowerPacks" tools.

Comment: If you select all controls, then copy them and then delete them that would work as suggested above. But all events coupled to any of the controls will be uncoupled also !! Beter is to drag all controls off the panel direct onto the form or wherever you want them, and then delete the panel, and then put all controls back to where you want them. This way all controls will keep all their events coupled

Comment: @GuidoG that's not how the Panel object works. You can't drag objects off of it. Everything automatically locks onto the Panel and when you try to move them, the Panel moves with them even when it isn't selected. If only the Panel is selected and you delete it, all the other objects are deleted too. Like I said, the Rectangle object works the way you are describing and that's what I used in place of the Panel.

Comment: I dont understand what the panel object has to do with my comment. I am saying that when you copy a control and delete it, and then paste the control back, all the events that where set for this control will not be set back to it. You are talking about something else

Comment: And yes you can drag objects off a panel control.

Comment: there is no trick, just select them and drag them off. All you have to do is make sure that when you select the controls you also not accidently select the panel also. I did this many times

Comment: Is the form where this panel is on maybe inherited from another form ? And the controls where placed on the panel in this parent form ? If that is the case than you cannot move the controls off the panel using the designer, only in code

Comment: I just tried to make a test form and you're right, I was able to drag the objects off. The original problem I had, the objects were connected to the panel and could not be dragged off. I don't know why. I had a fully functioning form and then, as a final touch, I added the panel for decoration. I have no idea why it binded itself to everything but they were inseparable until I did the copy everything/delete the panel/paste everything method.

Comment: I see. But by copying, deleting and then pasting back controls, these controls will have lost any events they had. You will have to do some puzzling to get that back in order. And that is why I said that moving them off the panel would be better because then they would not loose their events. I am curious as to why you where not able to drag them off  the panel

Comment: Fortunately they were all labels and read only text boxes and pictures so there were no events. But I can see where it would be a pain if there were. But, they did retain their names, so it would just be a matter of attaching the events back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is manual:

Select all your items in the panel one by one by holding down the control key, and then when done release control, and click Ctrl+C to copy. Then delete them. You are left with the panel, so you can delete it, and paste. All your items will be in their exact same location.

The second option is dynamic.

```
'Set items parents to the form behind, and send them to back. For example
   Label1.Parent = Form1
   Label1.SendtoBack()
' Then you enter the code to dispose of your panel
```

Hope that helps. Comment for further assistance.

Comment: deleting controls and then copying them back will work, but all events that are coupled to any of these controls will not be coupled back again !! You will have to write down first what events are coupled to what controls... This is lots of work. Better drag the controls direct to where you want them in stead of deleting them, then delete the panel, and then move the controls to the position you want them. This way you dont have to worry about any events getting lost in the process

Comment: @GuidoG Well I just had a suggestion. Seems you had a better idea.